# Displaying prices without tax only in certain product categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, categories, product

The product category is "Machines"

My website is: "https://www.floorcare-supplies.co.uk/product-category/machines/"

I'm looking to be able to display the products in this category specifically without the tax on the shop front.

I've managed to do it when on the products for example:

£1,342

£1123 Ex vat

But on the shop store, I need the main price to display the total without tax for that specific category.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
/**
 * Function that will check for category id and turn off VAT/tax 
 */
function wc_diff_rate_for_cat() {
    if (is_product_category ('machines')) {
        // set the machines category to have no VAT
        WC()->customer->is_vat_exempt = true;
    }
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'wc_diff_rate_for_cat', 1 );

/**
 * Function that filters the variable product hash based on category
 */
function wc_get_variation_prices_hash_filter( $hash, $item, $display ) {

    // check for the "machines" category
    if (is_product_category ('machines')) {

        // clear key 2, which is where taxes are
        $hash['2'] = array();
    }

    // return the hash
    return $hash;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_variation_prices_hash', 'wc_get_variation_prices_hash_filter', 1, 3 );

/**
 * Function that removes the price suffix (inc. Tax) from variable products based on category
 */
function wc_get_price_suffix_filter( $price_display_suffix, $item ) {

    if (is_product_category ('machines')) {

        // return blank if it matches
        return '';
    }

    // return if unmatched
    return $price_display_suffix;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_suffix', 'wc_get_price_suffix_filter', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but this doesn't work,  also I don't want the category tax exempt,  I just want it to show the price without tax rather than with on the shop

Answer (score 0):

Solved

Solution

Modified Child theme to include

Woocommerce\includes\wc-template-functions.php

&

woocommerce\loop\price.php

Code added to 
Woocommerce\includes\wc-template-functions.php

```
/**
 * Get the product price for the loop.
 *
 * @subpackage  Loop
 */
function woocommerce_template_loop_price() {
    wc_get_template( 'loop/pricemod.php' );

}
```

Then modified pricemod.php

```
global $product;
$vat = "Ex vat ";
?>
<p class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></p>
<p class="priceex"><?php echo woocommerce_price($product->get_price_excluding_tax()). ' ' .  $vat; ?></p>
```

Comment: Kindly, but **this is not a good solution** as you are **overriding core files**: Woocommerce\includes\wc-template-functions.php … The right way is to use the hook 'wc_price'. Alslo in your solution you are not targeting the "Machines" product category.

Answer (score 0):

To display **prices excluding tax only for your "Machines" product category**, you should use a custom function hooked in **`wc_price`** filter hook, this way:

```
add_filter( 'wc_price', 'product_category_price_excl_tax', 10, 3 );
function product_category_price_excl_tax(  $price_html, $price, $args ){
    global $post;

    // Price excluding taxes for "Machines" product category with corresponding label
    if( has_term( 'Machines', 'product_cat', $post->ID ) ){

        $decimal_separator  = wc_get_price_decimal_separator();
        $thousand_separator = wc_get_price_thousand_separator();
        $decimals           = wc_get_price_decimals();
        $price_format       = get_woocommerce_price_format();
        $number_format      = number_format( $price, $decimals, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator );
        $negative           = $price < 0;
        $currency = get_woocommerce_currency();

        // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
        $product = wc_get_product($post->ID);

        // Get the product price excluding taxes
        $price = wc_get_price_excluding_tax( $product, $price );

        $price = apply_filters( 'raw_woocommerce_price', floatval( $negative ? $price * -1 : $price ) );
        $price = apply_filters( 'formatted_woocommerce_price', $number_format, $price, $decimals, $decimal_separator, $thousand_separator );

        if ( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_price_trim_zeros', false ) && $decimals > 0 )
            $price = wc_trim_zeros( $price );

        $formatted_price = ( $negative ? '-' : '' ) . sprintf( $price_format, '<span class="woocommerce-Price-currencySymbol">' . get_woocommerce_currency_symbol( $currency ) . '</span>', $price );
        $price_html      = '<span class="woocommerce-Price-amount amount">' . $formatted_price . '</span>';

        if ( wc_tax_enabled() )
            $price_html .= ' <small class="woocommerce-Price-taxLabel tax_label">' . WC()->countries->ex_tax_or_vat() . '</small>';
    }
    return $price_html;
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

This code is tested and works for WooCommerce version 3+

---

Now, to display that prices **only** in "Machines" shop category archives pages, you will need to replace:

```
    if( has_term( 'Machines', 'product_cat', $post->ID ) ){
```

by:

```
    if( has_term( 'Machines', 'product_cat', $post->ID ) && is_product_category ('machines') ){
```